# Pasting unicode from external applications with mouse wheel on Unix

Tags: linux, clipboard

On upgrade from Emacs 24.3.1 to Emacs 25.0.50 pasting unicode from external applications with mouse wheel appears broken.

I start `emacs -Q` and select e.g. title of [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erdős](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s) wikipedia entry in firefox. However with mouse wheel I get

```
Paul_Erd\u0151s
```

where as with normal `clipboard-yank` works fine:

```
Paul_Erdős
```

Pasting the same with mouse wheel (aka `<mouse-2>`) from Emacs selection works fine.

Comment: I can confirm this; middle mouse click pastes unicode fine on emacs 24.5 but not on emacs 25.x (git master). You should file a bug report for this (`M-x report-emacs-bug`).

Comment: @kaushalmodi: done.

Comment: [**`debbugs # 20906`**](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20906)